# How to make a post request using request module NodeJs express

Tags: node.js, api, post, request

How to make a proper post request to this endpoint. When I use the POSTMAN I get the correct response but when I call using the below function I get 503 error. The call seems to be fine according to me. I appreciate your help!!

```
const request = require('request');
const express = require('express');

// Initialize request
var img64Data = "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2w… "; // Include the entire base64 encoding. // Shown Below in the next page 
var send = {"img64": img64Data};
var api_address = "https://8n78hbwks0.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/dev/";

// Make Post Request

module.exports = app => {
  app.post('/axe', (req, res, next) => {
    console.log("inside the axe");
    request.post({
      url: api_address,
      body: JSON.stringify(send),
      headers: {"Content-Type":"application/json"}
    }, function (error, response, body) {
      console.log("hiii");
      console.log(response.statusCode);
      if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        // Successful call
        var results = JSON.parse(body);
        console.log(results) // View Results
      }
    });
  });
};
```

Comment: why are you calling  request.post inside a post???¿? It´s like posting a posting??¿?¿

Comment: Could please guide me how to request it. That would be very helpful and appreciate your kindness.

Comment: Could you add to your question the raw format of the request made by postman?

Comment: (because the url via GET responde with "missing auth", and i think that postman is configured to add the auth token)

Answer (score 0):

You get a 503 Error https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes because your server doesn't reply any http code.

```
if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
  // Successful call
  var results = JSON.parse(body);
  console.log(results) // View Results
  res.sendStatus(200);
} else {
  res.sendStatus(response.statusCode);
}
```

Comment: I tried it but still the same error. Now it says as bad request. @user1851595

Comment: i've edited the code above, so it returns the http code from your request.post, it will tell what's the problem in your request.post.

Comment: then check the values of `api_address`, `send`, and `img64Data` are correct. i got a 503 too when i try to post with those values